# How can I print a list of derived .NET classes?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I am planning a migration of a large code base from CSLA to Entity Framework and I need to perform some analysis of the scope of work. Therefore, given a Visual Studio solution (or a set of .NET assemblies) I need to be able to find all classes that derive from a given base class (e.g. BusinessBase). My primary requirement is that I be able to copy this list to a text file.

Are there any free tools that have this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried Reflector? http://www.reflector.net/ Another option is that code it yourself. I think it isn't very complicated using reflection

Comment: I tried dotPeek and JustDecompile and neither has such an option. I haven't touched Reflector since Red Gate gobbled it up but they have a free trial so I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Bingo! Reflector meets my need for now, but I really would like a free tool that did this.

Comment: I think that using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` you can accomplish the task with a little programming effort

Comment: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can also do this type of search. It too has a free trial.  Also [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) has a free trial and is designed exactly for this type of code analysis.

Comment: I have to say, if thirty five bucks isn't worth your time then you are doing something drastically wrong.  Selling life insurance pays better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a relatively simple way to do this in code be something like:

```
var derivedTypes = from t in Assembly.GetAssembly("BusinessObjects").GetTypes()
                   where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BusinessBase))
               select t;
```

Comment: This would only list types from within the "BusinessObjects" assembly, so one would have to do this for every assembly in the codebase.

Comment: True, but it would be pretty trivial to iterate the Assemblies you want to scan.